# Changing the font color in VBA chart Series

Tags: excel, vba, pie-chart

I am using below code to color my pies in Pie chart so that each pie will have the same color of its value range. This code is working fine.

```
for I = 1 to UBound (vntValues)
   myseries.Points(I).Interior.color = Range(s).cells(I).interior.color
next I
```

I want to change the font color of each pie according to the its value range. I tried below code but its not working.

```
myseries.Points(I).Font.color = Range(s).cells(I).Font.color
```

Its giving the error as

> object doesn't support this property or method.

Can you please help me with the correct method to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semi-tested:

```
mySeries.Points(I).DataLabel.Characters.Font.Color = Range(s).cells(I).Font.color
```